# No such file or directory python in linux only (coming from windows)

Tags: python

I have the same exact directory structure within a folder in Windows & in Linux (Debian) - where the script is along the static + dataoutput folders

How come the following code works fine in Windows, but gives a no such file or directory path error in linux?

```
@app.route('/_getdataoutputfilelisting')
def getdataoutputfilelisting():
    listoffilesindataouput = getfiles('static/dataoutput')
    return jsonify(listoffiles = listoffilesindataouput) 

def getfiles(dirpath):
    a = [s for s in os.listdir(dirpath)
         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirpath, s))]
    a.sort(key=lambda s: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dirpath, s)))
    a.reverse()
    return a
```

Is there a way to make it universal such that it works in both OSs?

Thanks

Comment: No such file or directory: 'static/dataoutput'

Comment: i had the same problem once, try using `//` instead of `/`.

Comment: That's a relative path. What is the current directory of the process?

Answer (score 1):

I would try changing the string your passing into getfiles.

Try this instead:

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'static','dataoutput')
```

I cannot verify that it'll work in Windows, but that works in Linux; whereas `'static/dataoutput'` won't.

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Linux have different path separators. For Windows, parts of the path are separated by a backward slash (<kbd>\</kbd>), while on Linux it's a forward slash (<kbd>/</kbd>). You can use `os.path.join('static', 'dataoutput')` as @mcneo suggested (even without `getcwd()`) or create the path on your own with `os.path.sep`.

```
getfiles(os.path.join('static', 'dataoutput'))
# or...
getfiles('static' + os.path.sep + 'dataoutput')
```

Technically you can also check for the platform and put the correct slash in, but that's not recommended. I'm adding it here to better demonstrate the problem, but you should use `os.path`.

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
  getfiles('static\\dataoutput')
else:
  getfiles('static/dataoutput')
```

Answer (score -1):

It probably has something to do with the way DOS and Unix treat things like newlines and returns differently. Try `dos2unix` tool to convert the file.

```
SYNOPSIS
           dos2unix [options] [FILE ...] [-n INFILE OUTFILE ...]
           unix2dos [options] [FILE ...] [-n INFILE OUTFILE ...]
```